# Weird results from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a page with some radio buttons as well as a graph and legend.  When the radio buttons change on onchange method is called and this should do two things: 
1.  change which portion of the legend is showing
2.  redraw the graph using the appropriate data.

Here is a clip of the HTML:

```
<div id="divDailyRadioButtons" style="width:300px; ">
    <div class="divDailyRadio" style="left:25;top:50;"><input type="radio" name="radTotalHours" value="Total" onchange="sm_controller.Events_OnChangeDailyGraphsRadios();"  />Total Hours</div>
    <div class="divDailyRadio" style="left:25; top:75;"><input type="radio" name="radTotalHours" value="CF" onchange="sm_controller.Events_OnChangeDailyGraphsRadios();" />Customer-Facing</div>
    <div class="divDailyRadio" style="left:25; top:100;"><input type="radio" name="radTotalHours" value="NCF" onchange="sm_controller.Events_OnChangeDailyGraphsRadios();" />Non-Customer Facing</div>
</div>
```

Here is a clip of the function:

```
switch($('input[name=radTotalHours]:checked').val())
{
    case 'Total':
        $('#rowDailyCFGraphsLegend').show();
        $('#rowDailyNCFGraphsLegend').show();
        break;
    case 'CF':
        $('#rowDailyCFGraphsLegend').show();
        $('#rowDailyNCFGraphsLegend').hide();
        break;
    case 'NCF':
        $('#rowDailyCFGraphsLegend').hide();
        $('#rowDailyNCFGraphsLegend').show();
        break;
}
```

Ok so here is the weirdness... The value I'm getting isn't the value of the radio button that is selected but the *previous* radio button.  After a bit of searching, I added some console.log lines to check:

```
console.log('val1: ' + $('input:radio[name=radTotalHours]').val());
console.log('val2: ' + $('input:radio[name=radTotalHours]:checked').val());
console.log('val3: ' + $('input[name=radTotalHours]').val());
console.log('val4: ' + $('input[name=radTotalHours]:checked').val());
```

val1 and val3 always display "Total" while val2 and val4 always match but display the *previous* radio button's value.

I even added the following:

```
$('input', '#divDailyRadioButtons').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')
        console.log('val: ' + $(this).val());
    else
            console.log('xxx');
});
```

But here the if statement *always* passes for 'Total', no matter which radio is selected.

As a side note, I am forced to use IE9 for this.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: `.attr('checked')` gets the attribute from the HTML, not the current state of the button.

Comment: It works as expected for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/w1225dmq/1/

Comment: Yeah, the fiddler works exactly as i'd like.  I just can't get it to work in the app. :-(

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would work differently. The `onchange` handler is called at the same time, and I use the same selector.

Comment: Are you using any kind of library or framework that changes the way the radio buttons are displayed?

Comment: It's possible that something is overwriting it but that would be a really strange thing to overwrite.  As a side note, onclick works correctly.  However, I don't want to use onclick because then it will fire every time, even if the value isn't changed.  The graphing function is a little slow (about 300ms) so I really don't want to call that if I don't have to.  I could use onclick and save the value for future comparison but that's just so clunky for such a simple thing.

Comment: Something seems to be calling your handler before the change actually takes effect. I can't think of what would be doing that. Try putting a breakpoint in the handler, then look at the call stack to see where it's being called from.

Comment: I don't suppose you can provide a link to the live site. WIthout being able to reproduce this, I don't see how we can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: There is no live site for this unfortunately.  It's... complicated....  it's just how we do it here where I work.  On the positive side, I came up with a couple of solutions.  All are stupid, but they work...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `switch($('input[name=radTotalHours]:checked').val())`, try to use `$(this)`:

```
function yourRadioChangeHandler() {
   switch($(this).val()) // here 'this' is a changed radio object
   {
      case 'Total':
         $('#rowDailyCFGraphsLegend').show();
         $('#rowDailyNCFGraphsLegend').show();
         break;
      case 'CF':
         $('#rowDailyCFGraphsLegend').show();
         $('#rowDailyNCFGraphsLegend').hide();
         break;
      case 'NCF':
         $('#rowDailyCFGraphsLegend').hide();
         $('#rowDailyNCFGraphsLegend').show();
         break;
   }
}

<div class="divDailyRadio" style="left:25;top:50;"><input type="radio" name="radTotalHours" value="Total" onchange="yourRadioChangeHandler();"  />Total Hours</div>
```

Comment: 'this' would point the my controller object.  It only worked in my original post because I was inside of the .each.  I liked your idea though and added (this) to the html onchange and changed my function in accordance.  I added ScheduleManagerController.prototype.Events_OnChangeDailyGraphsRadios = function(target)
{
 console.log('val: ' + $(target).val());     but this actually does the same thing, still always getting the <em>previous</em> button's value.

Comment: When you use `onchange` like that, the context of the function is not the element you clicked on, it's `window`. You need to do `onchange="yourRadioChangeHandler(this)"` and then add a parameter to the handler function.

Comment: Barmar, I think we are saying the same thing.  I changed the onchange to `onchange="sm_controller.Events_OnChangeDailyGraphsRadios(this);"` and the function itself is `ScheduleManagerController.prototype.Events_OnChangeDailyGraphsRadios = function(target)' but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that there is a library being imported that has some bind events which are affecting how the radios work (as Barmar suggested).  I came up with two possible solutions, neither of which is *good* but they both work.

Solution 1:  Add an empty bind event for these radios.

```
$('input[name=radTotalHours]').change( function(){});
```

I think that somehow this either pauses the imported event or overwrites it.  I'm not exactly sure how/why, but suddenly the onchange does work correctly once this code is in place.

Solution 2:  Add a class to each radio matching it's value.  Add the *this* parameter to the onchange function and then use the class to determine which of the radio's function call is being executed with

```
$(target).attr('class');
```

Both of these solutions are totally stupid, but then again where I work that is the norm...

Anyways, thanks for the help guys.